# Is correct the expression "Where to trip"

Tags: word-choice, expressions, verbs, sentence

Is correct the expression "Where to trip" understanding "trip" as a travel.

For example:

I don't know where to trip.

Is it similar to the following?

I don't know where to go.
I don't know where to travel.

Maybe its an easy question but I ask it because I'm not a native english-speaker.

Comment: Personally, I've never heard that particular one used. But the sloppy use of nouns as verbs does widely occur.

Comment: As WS2 implies, _trip_ is not a verb. You _make_ or _take_ a trip somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a case of [verbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)#Verbification), but using trip for the sense of travelling or going on a trip is non-standard and would be strange (see @EdwinAshworth's comment for other formulations that may be strange).

[*Trip* is also a standard verb](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/trip_2), meaning to (make someone) fall due to an obstacle, to switch on/off an electronic circuit, to move with quick light steps and to use and feel psychedelic substances (in slang).

Comment: This is basically right, but slightly misleading.  First, the verb ‘trip’ can be used either intransitively (as in “I tripped over my shoelaces and fell into a puddle”) or transitively (as in “she was penalised for tripping the opposing striker inside the box”).  Second, it is worth saying that the commonly used intransitive verb derived from a noun  is ‘to tour’.  This also can be used transitively.

Comment: "I don't know where to go" is of course fully idiomatic, but care has to be taken when substituting other verbs of travel / locomotion. "I don't know where to walk/jog/run/hike/climb/swim/surf/sail/ski" are all acceptable, though "I don't know where to go hiking ..." would be more normal. "I don't know where to crawl" is possible, metaphorically at least. "I don't know where to fly/balloon/drive" are beginning to push the bounds. And "I don't know where to trip" sounds almost as bad as "I don't know where to hop/bound/cartwheel". Though we may trip to the church by morning-light (Browning).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I should make it more clear in my answer that it is strange to use I don't know where to trip for I don't know where to go. The sentence could make sense if you use trip in its ordinary verb senses though in some contexts, e.g. an actor asking the director where he should pretend to fall or someone wanting to know where it would be a safe place to use psychedelics.

Comment: to use 'trip' as a verb meaning 'to travel' is not non-standard. it is unusual.

Comment: @ArmthegoodguysinAmerica Could you clarify your comment?